# Publish updatable Java software through Wordpress

Tags: java, wordpress, maven, jar, java-web-start

I have just written a Java program that I now need to publish. I want to make the software easily updatable, and I therefore need your advice. The program will be used by people with minimal technical knowledge, hence usability is absolute key. The program is not open source.

**The situation is this:**
First time users download a zip-file containing one .jar-file and two folders that should contain the program output files (.xml-files and .png-files). I want to make it as easy as possible for the user to update the .jar (replace it with another .jar, not necessarily at run time). To my help I have a simple web-based Wordpress site that the user will view as the source of the program.

I'll list the possible solutions I've come up with:

**1 (fallback solution).** The user have to manually go to the Wordpress site where I'll put a separate direct download link (from Google Drive) for the .jar-file. The user then has to manually replace the .jar in the existing folder with the new one.
*The drawback to this is that it requires too much work from the user, and they program probably won't get updated very often.*

**2.** Alongside the Program.jar in the zip-file the first user downloads, I place another Program-Updater.jar. This new .jar's sole purpose is to, when the user opens it, download a new version of Program.jar from the web and replace the existing one.
*This is better than the previous option because it requires less work, even though it's not automatic. The drawback is that I need one more .jar which can confuse the user, and most importantly I have no way of updating the Program-Updater.jar.*

**3.** Java Web Start.
*I've tried reading up on how this works, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get it to work. One possible problem is that I can't really access the host, and to be able to set up the .jnlp the correct way I think you need this. I'm also wondering how the program's file structure would be (is the .jar even placed on the user's computer?) and if this could confuse the user. Also how to make it always work offline.*

**4.** Suggest your own solution!

Any input on this matter would be greatly appreciated, and I'll gladly give more info than I already have.

Cheers

Comment: If you use github, you can use their webhooks to send a json payload on a new git commit, and trigger a script to get the latest jarfile/compile it.

Comment: @Rogue Haven't come across Webhooks before, will definitely check it out! From what I can see webhooks is mainly used in web development, to make services like jenkins and jira listen to when a Git repo has changed. Is there actually a way to make my desktop .jar listen to the same events and start downloading a new file?

Comment: well realistically anything that listens on a port for a json payload from github can begin executing anything as a result from it

Comment: From your answer I've somehow discovered GetDown which seems very promising!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Getdown](https://github.com/threerings/getdown) was the way to go; it is extremely easy to use.

I'll put the .zip on Google Drive with a direct download link to it on my Wordpress site.

The files used by getdown are placed in and downloaded from my public git repo.

Comment: Now I've actually created an installer and put an .exe on the site instead.